# Manipulate xml through c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have following xml structure I want to update it through c#
How to update it 
Is it possible to update through Linq if yes then how to do it?
I want to add UnitTest, TestList, TestEntry and UnitTestResults elements through code.

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestRun id="1" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas">
     <TestDefinitions>
    <UnitTest name="Test1" id="T1">
      <Execution id="E1" />   
    </UnitTest>
    <UnitTest name="Test2" id="T2">
      <Execution id="E2" />   
    </UnitTest>
        :
        :

  </TestDefinitions>
    <TestLists>
    <TestList name="List1" id="L1" />
    <TestList name="List2" id="L2" />
     :
      :

  </TestLists>
  <TestEntries>
    <TestEntry testId="T1" executionId="E1" testListId="L1" />
    <TestEntry testId="T2" executionId="E2" testListId="L2" />
    :
    :
  </TestEntries>
  <Results>
    <UnitTestResult executionId="E1" testId="T1" testName="Test1" >
      <Output>
        <ErrorInfo>
          <Message>Hi</Message>
        </ErrorInfo>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
  </Results>
  <Results>
    :
    :
</TestRun>
```

`

Comment: I'd consider investigating XSLT. With a well-designed XSLT sheet, you can transform your XML into any form you want, such as an xhtml document that displays your data in a user-friendly way. Then your C# code becomes trivial, you just apply the transform, or you can just add the stylesheet declaration to your xml, and open it in any browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by LINQ. This is the example code to add new `UnitTest` element:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "tests.xml" );
XNamespace ns = "http://microsoft.com/schemas";

XElement unitTest = new XElement( ns + "UnitTest",
    new XElement( ns + "Execution", new XAttribute( "id", "E3" ) ),
    new XAttribute( "name", "Test3" ),
    new XAttribute( "id", "T3" ) );
doc.Root.Element( ns + "TestDefinitions" ).Add( unitTest );

doc.Save( "tests.xml" );
```

To add the element you must create the `XElement` object and pass to its constructor the name of the new element and all its stuff like child elements, attributes (through a comma). Then you must specify where you want to add new element: by going from the Root element through the XML three (like in this example) or by query.

You can find needed element by LINQ query. Next example shows how to get all `TestEntries` from the `TestList` with id `L1`:

```
var query = from e in doc.Root.Elements( ns + "TestEntries" ).Elements()
            where e.Attribute( "testListId" ).Value == "L1"
            select new
            {
                TestId = e.Attribute( "testId" ).Value,
                ExecutionId = e.Attribute( "executionId" ).Value
            };

foreach ( var testEntry in query )
{
    Console.WriteLine( testEntry.TestId + " " + testEntry.ExecutionId );
}
```

Result objects from this query have anonymous type with useful properties. If you want work with `XElement` objects, simply change `select new ...` to `select e`.

If you want update the value of the element, find it (look above) and call the `SetValue()` method.

If you working with namespaces (like you file) you must create `XNamespace` object with needed value and concatenate it with all elements' names that you need.

To save your changes to the xml file on dist, call `Save()` method.

[LINQ to XML Overview in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb308960.aspx)

Comment: I gave you a +1; but where is the LINQ?

Comment: It is a part of LINQ to XML. Other part is to find the needed elements (queries). I will update my answer with example.